# How to set Slack reminder for a range of dates

Tags: slack, reminders

For example, I want a reminder to appear each day in a specific channel for the days I am off. Something like:

```
/remind #channel @me will be on PTO 1/1/2016 until 1/5/2016
```

And then each day in that range a reminder will appear in the channel saying the range of dates.

What would be the command/syntax to achieve that or as close to that as possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Edit: **outdated, no longer works**]

The following worked.

```
/remind #channel "@me will be on PTO from 1/1/2016 until 1/5/2016." every weekday until 1/5
```

It results in the following being posted every weekday at 9am in #channel

> "@me will be on PTO from 1/1/2016 until 1/5/2016."

Comment: Results in `I will remind caoilte “"@me will be on PTO from 1/1/2016 until 1/5/2016." every weekday until” at 9:00 Friday, January 5th, 2018.`

Comment: This answer is outdated and should not be the accepted answer.

Comment: It does not work