# Set reminder in slack

Tags: slack, reminders, slack-commands

I am setting reminder in slack. How do I set reminder in slack till a particular date?

I want my reminder to appear everyday at a particular time **till a particular date**

e.g: remind me "to cook" at 8.00 until 12/31

I tried this 
    /remind me "to cook" at 8.00 until 12/31

```
Expected: I will remind you to "cook" at 8AM every weekday until 12/31

Actual: I will remind you to “cook at 8.00 every weekday until” at 9AM Tuesday, December 31st.
```

EDIT: The question([How to set Slack reminder for a range of dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41245985/how-to-set-slack-reminder-for-a-range-of-dates)) does not answer my question. The accepted answer there is not working.

Comment: You can do everyday? I don't see any  mentions on Slack page

Comment: https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/208423427-Set-a-reminder

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set Slack reminder for a range of dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41245985/how-to-set-slack-reminder-for-a-range-of-dates)

Comment: @MatejMecka The solution given there is not working.

Comment: I vote to close this question, because it does not appear to be about a programming related question. A good alternative for asking questions about how to use web apps like Slack is this forum: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/